# What is the fastest search method for array?

Tags: c#, .net

I have array class of the length 1000^2.

Array contain numbers between 10-1000.

What is the fastest way to get all the numbers in array between 200-300?

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(200, 100).ToArray()`

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Sorting it will help.

Comment: A simple for/foreach loop. Moreover it you're trying to build an histogram then you could count all the range [200-300[ [300-400[ together so that you only scan the array once...

Comment: @SLaks: do you know a O(n) (not parallel) sort? ;)

Comment: @Pragmateek: I'm assuming he wants to search more than once.

Comment: @SLaks: OK if the collection is static, but often it can be done in one pass, i.e. O(n); if this is dynamic we need a sorted collection. :)

Comment: We really need more details: how many times that kind of search will be performed? Did you already try any method?

Comment: @Pragmateek: Sure, the setup here with the restricted range is a fantastic candidate for a bucket sort.

Comment: The array contains the results from histogram
Array arr_Hue = channels[0].ManagedArray;

I want to run through it  olny once

Comment: Is the data sorted? That changes things s lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the fastest way to get all the numbers in array between 200-300?

The fastest is probably an O(n).

Loop through all elements in your array and if the current element is in the desired range, add it to the result list.

```
List<int> result = new List<int>();
for (var i = 0; i < yourOriginalArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (yourOriginalArray[i] >= 200 && yourOriginalArray[i] <= 300)
    {
        result.Add(yourOriginalArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use LINQ:

```
List<int> result = yourOriginalArray.Where(x => x >= 200 && x <= 300).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) method like;

```
var array = array.Where(n => n <= 300 && n >= 200).ToList();
```

Comment: If you're leveraging LINQ avoid calling ToList() too soon so that you benefit from **deferred evaluation** too. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are going to use an array of that size it would be nice if you first sort it then using binary_search algorithm you can get index of first 200 happening and index of last 300 happeinnig in the array and then return the between elements.
This would be the fastest way to retrieve elements.

Comment: How would that be the fastest way? You can solve it in linear O(N) time, but sorting is O(N(Log(N))

Comment: it depends on the situation , if u have enough time to pre compute (sort) then it is logical to do so , if the retrieves numbers is considerable then in overall it would be fastest possible way.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Array arr = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 1000000);
    Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();            

    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) 
    {
        arr.SetValue(random.Next(10, 1000), i);
    }

    List<int> loopFor = new List<int>();
    time.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) 
    {
        int value = (int)arr.GetValue(i);
        if (value >= 200 && value <= 300) 
        {
            loopFor.Add(value);
        }
    }
    time.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Loop for: {0}", time.Elapsed);

    time.Reset();
    time.Start();
    List<int> loopForeach = new List<int>();
    foreach (int i in arr)
    {
        if (i >= 200 && i <= 300)
        {
            loopForeach.Add(i);
        }
    }
    time.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Loop foreach: {0}", time.Elapsed);

    time.Reset();
    time.Start();
    int[] matchedItems = Array.FindAll((int[])arr, x => x >= 200 && x <= 300);
    time.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Array.FindAll: {0}", time.Elapsed);
    Console.Read();
```

```
Result:
LoopFor: 1102804 milisseconds
Loop foreach: 1086569 milisseconds
Array.FindAll: 14 milisseconds (Better)
```