# What is the fastest way to return a range of numbers from a sorted array of numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays, search, find

For C++ language, what's the fastest way in processing run-time (in multi core processors), from an algorithm design viewpoint, to search numbers (e.g. between 100 and 1000) that are within an array (or splice or whatever faster data structures for the purpose of this) and return the range of numbers limited to only 10 items returned? e.g. pseudocode in golang:

```
var listofnums := []uint64 
var numcounter := 1
// splice of [1,2,3,4,5,31,32 .. 932536543] this list has 1 billion numeric items.
// the listofnums are already sorted each time an item is added but we do not know the lower_bound or upper_bound of the item list.
// I know I can use binary search to find listofnums[i] where it is smallest at [i] too... I'm asking for suggestions. 
for i:=uint(0); i < len(listofnums); i++ {
    if listofnums[i] > 100 && listofnums[i] < 1000 {
         if listofnums[i]> 1000 || numcounter == 10 {
             return
         }
         fmt.Println("%d",listofnums[i])
         numcounter++
    }
}
```

is this the fastest way? I saw bitmap structures in C++ but not sure if can be applied here.

I've come across this question, which is perfectly fine for veteran programmers to ask but I have no idea why it's down voted.
[What is the fastest search method for array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133768/what-is-the-fastest-search-method-for-array)

Can someone please not remove this question but let me rephrase it? Thanks in advance. I hope to find the most optimum way to return a range of numbers from a large array of numeric items.

Comment: Which language? Choose one

Comment: I need to test if Go's memory requirement and usage is worth implementation than C++'s fastest way of doing this range return. So... is this ok? I mean, if Go uses too much memory just to accomplish this, then I will use C++ or vice versa. Fastest also have to depend on whether it's worth the implementation of it (considering a lot more factors than just pure speed)

Comment: It also depends on what else you know about the data. For example, if already the second element matches `> 100` then your search is fast. If we don't know anything, a binary search would be better. In C++ you have [lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) for that.

Comment: First, you should still ask about one language per question, or the question is too board. Second, your definition of "fastest" is too vague. Is it time complexity, run-time, or development time? Third, this kind of algorithm is language-agnostic. Forth, language overhead and algorithm design are two questions.

Comment: Ok, I removed the Go part. Use C++ then. I didn't know I had to be this specific. This is my second question on stackoverflow. For a newbie, how can I improve the question fast enough and meaningful to get up votes? :)

Comment: For Go, use [sort.Search](https://godoc.org/sort#Search) to find the index of the start and end of the range. Return slice with that range. No memory is allocated.

Comment: Does this boil down to asking the fastest way to find two numbers in an array?

Comment: No, the fastest way to find a range of array. In fact, just return a limited list will do. e.g. return only 10 items from the list. I will re-edit the question again. Thanks for asking to clear it up.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Will look it up. I can't ask more questions now but I will do so for Go language. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: But you need to find the element above and including which the numbers are equal to or greater than `100` and another element below which the numbers are less than or equal to `1000`? Those two elements mark the start and end of your range?

Comment: @Galik yes. is that the fastest way to get this done? else, is there a better way to get this done?

Comment: @Sam -- *In fact, just return a limited list will do. e.g. return only 10 items from the list.*  -- It would be better if a "view" of the data is returned to you, not an entire new subarray of `n` items that would require more memory to be allocated.  That's why returning two iterators denoting the start and end of the list is more preferable IMO.  That paradigm is also part and parcel of things such as `std::string_view`, where you're not having to create substrings if all you want is a view into an existing string.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly you need to find two positions in your array, the first of which all numbers are greater than or equal to `100` and the second of which all numbers are less than or equal to `1000`.

The functions [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [std::upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) do binary searches designed to find such a range.

For arrays, in `C++` we usually use a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and denote the beginning and end of ranges using a pair of *iterators*.

So something like this may be what you need:

```
std::pair<std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator>
    find_range(std::vector<int>& v, int min, int max)
{
    auto begin = std::lower_bound(std::begin(v), std::end(v), min);

    // start searching after the previously found value
    auto end = std::upper_bound(begin, std::end(v), max);

    return {begin, end};
}
```

You can iterate over that range like this:

```
auto range = find_range(v, 100, 1000);

for(auto i = range.first; i != range.second; ++i)
    std::cout << *i << '\n';
```

You can create a new vector from the range (slow) like this:

```
std::vector<int> selection{range.first, range.second};
```

Comment: can it limit the number of items returned to 10 or some specific values?

Comment: @Sam -- you are returned where the beginning and ending items are located.

Comment: @Sam No it simply returns the beginning and end of the range. But you can select ten from within that range.

Comment: @Sam On the contrary. I would think this method was extremely fast. I don't know of a quicker method of locating a sorted value than *binary search* (which this uses). By returning two *iterators* you also avoid the cost of making a copy of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

My first attempt.

Features:

- logN time complexity
- creates an array slice, no copying of data
- second binary search minimises the search space on the basis of the first

possible improvements:

- if n is small, the second binary search would be a pessimisation. Better to simply count forward up to n times.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

template <class Iter> struct range
{
    range(Iter first, std::size_t size) : begin_(first), end_(first + size) {}

    auto begin() const { return begin_; }
    auto end() const { return end_; }

    Iter begin_, end_;
};

template<class Iter> range(Iter, std::size_t) -> range<Iter>;

auto find_first_n_between(std::vector<std::int64_t>& vec, 
                          std::size_t n, 
                          std::int64_t from, std::int64_t to)
{
    auto lower = std::lower_bound(begin(vec), end(vec), from);
    auto upper = std::upper_bound(lower, end(vec), to);
    auto size = std::min(n, std::size_t(std::distance(lower, upper)));
    return range(lower, size);
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::int64_t> vec { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,15,17,18,19,20 };
    auto slice = find_first_n_between(vec, 5, 6, 15);

    std::copy(std::begin(slice), std::end(slice), std::ostream_iterator<std::int64_t>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```

Comment: how do you run this script again? i tried -std=c++11 but it shows 

script.cc:11:23: warning: ‘begin’ function uses ‘auto’ type specifier without trailing return type [enabled by default]
          auto begin() const { return begin_; }

Comment: I compiled  it with c++17